# How to access Modeling Input Parameters via Ocean API?

Tags: ocean, petrel

In `Models` tab, if I right click in a Facies, for instance, I can access a table called `Modeling Input Parameters`.

I can also do it via `Process Tab/Property modeling/Facies modeling`, click `Common` and click on `Show modeling input parameters`...

I would like to access this table via `Ocean API`, is this possible?